# Changing Branding on SF Welcome Email

Tags: email-template, administration, email-alert, customization

Is there any way to change the branding on the Salesforce Welcome email? (see screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot customize welcome email template.Please vote this ideas

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KCKTAA4

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrGfAAK